# Elasticsearch postings highlighter failing for some search strings

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a search that works well with most search strings, but fails spectacularly on others. Experimenting, it appears to fail when at least one word in the query doesn't match (like this made up search phrase), with the error:

```
{
   "error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query_fetch], all shards failed; shardFailures {[w3zfoix_Qi-xwpVGbCbQWw][ia_test][0]: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[the field [content] should be indexed with positions and offsets in the postings list to be used with postings highlighter]}]",
   "status": 400
}
```

The simplest search which gives this error is the one below:

```
POST /myindex/_search
{
    "from" : 0,
    "size" : 25,
    "query": {
        "filtered" : {
            "query" : {
                "multi_match" : {
                    "type" : "most_fields",
                    "fields": ["title", "content", "content.english"],
                    "query": "Box Fexye"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "highlight" : {
        "fields" : {
            "content" : {
                "type" : "postings"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My query is more complicated than this, and I need to use the "postings" highlighter to pull out the best matching sentence from a document.

Indexing of the relevant fields looks like:

```
        "properties" : {
            "title" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "fields": {
                    "shingles": {
                        "type":     "string",
                        "analyzer": "my_shingle_analyzer"
                    }
                }
            },
            "content" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "analyzer" : "standard",
                "fields": {
                    "english": {
                        "type":     "string",
                        "analyzer": "my_english"
                    },
                    "shingles": {
                        "type":     "string",
                        "analyzer": "my_shingle_analyzer"
                    }
                },
                "index_options" : "offsets",
                "term_vector" : "with_positions_offsets"
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try adding '"index_options" : "offsets"' into each field in content